# Open source deployment validation tool

Tags: testing, deployment, open-source, continuous-integration

I'm looking for an Open source tool to help with deployment validation for mainly web based applications on Windows machines (if it works with linux as well would be a huge bonus).  Basically I'm looking for an automatic validation of deployment to run prior to smoke tests of the application itself.  I'd like a data driven tool that would validate after deployments that everything is delivered (correct time stamps and versions), service is up and running, etc.  We could definitely build something to do this, but I was surprised when I didn't find anything like it out there.  Anyone know of any open source tools that will do this?

Comment: Got the tumbleweed badge... I guess there aren't any Open source deployment validation tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to reasonable answers on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1761/open-source-deployment-validation-tool

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too clear what you are asking for but take a look at [Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) as a starting point.